# Unable to start the jenkins in amazon linux machine

Tags: java, jenkins, devops, aws-devops

I try to start the Jenkins, im facing this error

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-245 ~]# systemctl start jenkins
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and my java version is
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS

And show only the activating status

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-245 ~]# systemctl status jenkins
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Sun 2022-05-08 14:46:00 UTC; 169ms ago
 Main PID: 20507 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
           └─20507 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=%C/jenkins/war --httpPort=...

May 08 14:46:00 ip-10-0-1-245.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server...
```

kindly help to resolve this issue

Comment: Is Java installed and set?